# Launch Windows tray application from cmd

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

How can I launch Windows tray application in separate window from cmd?

Please note: I have already used start command to launch the application but it is just running the process of application in Task Manager, not launching it. However, the same application can be launched by clicking on it from tray.

Comment: You need to clarify what you actually want. Which application? Which tray icon? Which program did you launch that didn't do what you want? I really don't get what you want.

Comment: Hey,I just want to launch bluecoat proxy client application which appears at system tray.This may help me in making batch script to launch same application at multiple computers at the same time.

Comment: I don't know bluecoat, try adding `-tray` or `-silent` to the extension when you launch it. Worth a go.

Comment: Not 100% certain, but if an application is designed to be launched from the tray, it may not have  another way of being launched.

Answer (score 2):

A program needs to be programmed specially so as to be able minimize to the
notification area in the system tray and still be functional.
It must call a Windows API function, specify its icon and context-menu
and be ready to act upon that menu.
Otherwise, if not programmed for it, it can only be minimized to the taskbar.

To minimize to the traybar a program which was not programmed for it, requires
then a specialized product.

A commercial product that can do this is
[Actual Window Minimizer](https://www.actualtools.com/windowminimizer/)
(commercial 19.95 USD).

A free solution uses a script for the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).
The script is published in the post
[Minimize Window to Tray Menu](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/MinimizeToTrayMenu.htm)
and creates two hotkeys for minimizing and un-minimizing the active windows.

When run, the script will show a green "H" icon on the traybar.
When using the minimize hotkey, it will cleverly hide that window
so that it doesn't show on the taskbar, and will add an entry for
that window inside its own tray menu.
If the script is terminated, it will first unhide all the hidden windows.

Some more such AutoHotkey scripts can be found in the posts:

- [Simple minimize to tray](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/32487-simple-minimize-to-tray/)
- [Minimize to tray](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/124024-minimize-to-tray/)

These scripts can be adapted for similarly starting and minimizing
to the tray a program.